# Using free() after realloc()

Tags: c, memory-management

If we use realloc() to extend an array, do we need to call free() on the pointer to the old array? Realloc() sometimes extends using the same spot in memory, so I'm worried calling free() will then free my newly expanded array.

Also, is using realloc() a good idea for deep copying arrays?

Comment: No, you don't. The old pointer automagically becomes invalid if the `realloc` call succeeds.

Comment: "is using realloc() a good idea for deep copying arrays?" No. `realloc` isn't guaranteed to perform deep copies of arrays. Nor is that it's intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If we use realloc() to extend an array, do we need to call free() on the pointer to the old array?

No. If `realloc()` succeeds then `realloc()` will handle memory management for the old pointer you passed (this is why `realloc()` requires you to pass a pointer that was allocated using malloc/calloc/realloc or NULL. If `NULL` is passed to `realloc()` then it's equivalent to calling `malloc()` with the same requested size).

From [7.22.3.5 The realloc function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5p2):

> From **The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr** and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size. The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values.

(emphasis mine).

You only need to `free()` if the call to `realloc()` fails. For example:

```
/* 'old_ptr' was allocated using malloc/realloc/calloc or it's NULL. */
char *new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);
if (!new_ptr) {
   perror("realloc");
   free(old_ptr);
   exit(1);
}
old_ptr = new_ptr;
...
```

is a common pattern of `realloc()` usage.

> is using realloc() a good idea for deep copying arrays?

That really depends on the specific use-case. Calling `realloc()` too often may not desirable (for example, realloc'ing 1 byte more than the previous size can result in a lot of copying). Typically, the *new size* is increased using a good strategy based on the application. Doubling it every time you need to `realloc()` is a common strategy.

Answer (score 2):

If `realloc` is successful, you shall **not** call free on the old pointer; `realloc` has taken care about that.

Comment: Thanks. I read this documentation about 3 times and wasn't able to find it anywhere in there :/ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html

Comment: @user3724404 - In the link you provided in the comment above, notice this line: "If the new size of the memory object would require movement of the object, the space for the previous instantiation of **the object is freed**"

Comment: And if the new size does NOT require movement of the object? Then what happens to the old pointer? It can't be freed as that would free the stuff the new pointer pointers to...

Comment: @user3724404 - That makes no difference. When you assign the the value returned by `realloc` to the old pointer, you still got the handle to the memory that you need to free later.